# Undefined symbol when importing OpenEXR in Python script

Tags: python, linux, linker-errors, openexr

I want to load EXR images in a Python script. Thus I imported it with

```
import OpenEXR
```

but unfortunately I am getting the following error when I start my script with

```
ipython testscript.py
```

Error Message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
PATH_TO_SCRIPT/testscript.py in <module>()
      8 import numpy as np
      9 # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---> 10 import OpenEXR
     11 
     12 # import dts_input

ImportError: PATH_TO_SCRIPT/OpenEXR.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN7Imf_2_27OStreamE
```

I have installed OpenEXR with Arch Linux's package manager and the binding module for python locally with

```
pip install --target ./ openexr
```

and a file called OpenEXR.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so has been installed in the script folder.

I have no idea how to solve the linking problem since it seams to be a linking error relating to OpenEXR's own imf library.

Comment: David, Any update on this? Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I have a similar query too